# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFUser", referenced from:

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running the InAppRage application (i am using Xcode 7.2 and iOS 9.3)  that is i am going to implement this code in my application. while running this example code, i got errors. anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Things I've tried:

- Changed the Architectures in Build Setting to Standard Architectures (armv7, arm64)
- Changed Build active Architecture only to No.

thanks advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version of the Parse framework does not support `arm64`.  Get an updated version.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Parse are you using? arm64 support was not included until v1.2.15 . update the latest version `1.13.0` and above your problem will Resolve.